# Get street addresses from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, address

I want to get the street addresses for all the buildings in London from OpenStreetMap, but I'm not sure how to request for it?

Can someone tell me what request predicate I should use?

Comment: You need an dump or an service that covers just london?

Comment: Just London, but I need the street addresses since I'm trying to make an locator

Answer (score 1):

You want to make use of (your own) [Nominatim geocoder](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). Or you use an [data extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) and filter it for objects with [addr:* tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:addr).

Comment: what address tags should I use?

Comment: Answer that by yoursekf by: what address tags do you NEED?  see the link from user Mapper into the OSM wiki about "addr: tagging" ... maybe if you are not so familiar with OSM data structure see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements first.

Comment: Also see the OSM wiki about http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm for downloading raw data, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter about filtering those country extracts, or alternatively http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo to get filtered OSM data by own queries ... for testing purposes.